# How to get a IIS 10.0 Express Web Service to use a Fixed Port Number When Using the VS 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, localhost

I'm new in ASPNet MVC framework but I have the minimum concept of MVC.
I have developed different MVC project in laravel I was using xampp server for my project.

And then the webserver provides link like https://localhost/myapp/ where I was using fixed port in xampp server.

But now in IIS Web Services providing me [https://localhost:44394/myapp/](https://localhost:44394/myapp)

I want to keep fixed or without the port number while  I reopen the solution.

I am trying to get the url in fixed port but not in random port number.

Comment: You might run a report to learn more about your project setup, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html Share the report as part of your question, and others then know what exactly you are working on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For running the project locally with Visual Studio and IIS Express, your URL would be something like https://localhost:44394/myapp/

Try the following to specify a fixed port number for a web application project using IIS Express.

> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the web application and select Properties. Click the Web tab.
> 2. In the Servers section, under dropdown selection for IIS Express, change the port number in the Project URL box.
> 3. To the right of the Project URL box, click Create Virtual Directory, and then click OK.
> 4. Save your changes, either by CTRL+S or clicking Save Selected Items that you will find in the File-menu.
> 5. To verify the change, press CTRL+F5 to run the project. Now it should use the fixed port number you specified instead of a random one.

From [how to set/change port number for a project using IIS Express in Visual Studio](https://blog.novacare.no/how-to-change-portnumber-for-sql-express-development/)